# I cannot lock my MacBook Pro with Shift + Alt + Eject shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have Apple keyboard (with numerical pad) connected to my MCP, but I can't lock my screen with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>. Is there other way to fastly lock screen or some way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the login window, select System Preferences from the Apple menu, then navigate to Security & Privacy > General. Check "Require password"

You will then set options for the duration within which to require a password. In your case, you want to set it to immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are all the keyboard combis that use the Eject key...

Presumably the one you want is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  <kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd>  
... but note that putting the screen to sleep doesn't necessarily trigger the login window when re-woken, depending on your Security & Privacy settings.

```
Power button
    Tap to turn on your Mac or wake your Mac from sleep.  
    Hold for 1.5 seconds while your Mac is awake to display a dialog asking  
    if you want to restart, sleep, or shut down. If you don't want to wait  
    1.5 seconds, press Control–Power button or Control–Media Eject  .

    Hold for 5 seconds to force your Mac to turn off.

Control–Command–Power button    
    Force your Mac to restart.  

Control–Shift–(Power button or Media Eject )    
    Put your displays to sleep.

Control–Command–Media Eject
    Quit all apps, then restart your Mac.  
    If any open documents have unsaved changes, you'll be asked whether  
    you want to save them.

Control–Option–Command–(Power button or Media Eject )
    Quit all apps, then shut down your Mac.   
    If any open documents have unsaved changes, you'll be asked whether  
    you want to save them.
```

Source : [Apple KB - Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236)

Comment: Eh, its just a bloper in my question... Ctrl ⌃ Shift ⇧ Eject ⏏ don't work, that is why I'm asking.